# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling, laravel-4

I recently launched my Laravel based site, and I had no problems, but 40 mins ago when I checked it I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 1 and `remember_token` = mfjLlbv3fR49TYGAqmUgBSqVVAKmoHhq26ws8rojuXxee5qWcvHrcdoTXs6W limit 1)
```

Why is this happening? Everything was okay and now suddenly I cannot do anything.

Comment: did you do composer update?

Comment: That value that *remember_token* is compared to is not quoted.

Comment: i deleted the sessions, now the error gone, but now its throwing the same error for the email, no i did not composer update

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs when mysqldump is in progress. It doesn't matter which DB dump is in progress. Wait for the dump to finish and this error will vanish.

The issue is with the table definition being dumped which cause this error.

Cheers,

Suren

Comment: if I have no dump in progress but instead get this error while running a query against a view? please elaborate your answer as it seems to cover only one of the possible cases and "wait it out" is a bit broad suggestion